# Calculating $ \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{\cos x \sin \sqrt{1+x^{2}}}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}} \mathrm{~d} x $

Tags: calculus, integration

$$
\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{\cos x \sin \sqrt{1+x^{2}}}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}} \mathrm{~d} x
$$
My idea: let $x = \sinh u$ and $\sqrt{1+x^2} = \cosh u$ then the formula simplified as
$$
\int_{0}^{+\infty} \cos({\sinh u)\sin(\cosh u)} \mathrm{~d} u
$$
I use wolframalpha to get
$$
\begin{align}
 &\int\cos({\sinh u)\sin(\cosh u)} \mathrm{~d} u \\
 &= 1/2 (-Si(\cosh(u) - \sinh(u)) + Si(\cosh(u) + \sinh(u)))
\end{align}
$$
where $Si(z) = \int_{0}^{z} \frac{\sin x}{x}\mathrm{d}x$
Is there any other answer ? Thank you.

Comment: You could apply product to sum formulas and a u-sub of $\sqrt{x^2+1} \pm x$ for each case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Continue with

\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{+\infty} \cos({\sinh u)\sin(\cosh u)} {~d} u\\
= &\frac12 \int_{0}^{+\infty} (\sin e^u + \sin e^{-u})du
= \frac12 \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \sin e^u du\overset{t=e^u}=\frac12\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin t}t dt
= \frac\pi4
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

Applying product to sum formulas and linearity we can rewrite the integral as:
$$\int_0^{+\infty}\left(\dfrac{\sin\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x\right)}{2\sqrt{x^2+1}}+\dfrac{\sin\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x\right)}{2\sqrt{x^2+1}}\right)\mathrm{d}x$$
Now using a u-sub of $u_1=\sqrt{x^2+1}+ x \ \text{and}\ u_2=\sqrt{x^2+1}-x $ for each case we reduce both integrands to:
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(u_1)}{u_1}-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(u_2)}{u_2}$$
Undoing the u-sub and solving special inetgrals we get:
$$\dfrac{\operatorname{Si}\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x\right)-\operatorname{Si}\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x\right)}{2}$$
Which can be evaluated at the desired limits.

Comment: x is from $0$ to $\infty$, are $u_1$ and $u_2$ also that?

Comment: No, when using a u-substitution one must take into account the change on the limits of the integral. You can do this by noticing that at $x=0 \to u_1,u_2=1$, so the lower bound must be changed to 1. By examining the behaviour of our functions $u_1,u_2$ as $x \to \infty$ we can see that the upper limit will remain at infinity. My apologies I did not make this clear in my answer.